# Forcing a verbose fsck on reboot (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, fsck

I'd like to force a verbose `fsck` on reboot of my Ubuntu linux server, I can get `fsck` to run on reboot by creating a file `/forcefsck` in my root dir ...

Additionally, by adding a `y` into the contents of the `/forcefsck` file my server will (properly) run `fsck` on reboot without any user interaction but every time I reboot (and let the auto fsck run) and then do ...

`fsck -nvf /dev/somedisk`

I still have the disk errors I had before, I even tried putting `yvf` in the text of the `/forcefsck` file with no luck.

Is there a simple way for me to force a verbose `fsck` on reboot?

***Note***: I've watched the `fsck` running at reboot and it does not come up with the same errors I get when I run `fsck -nvf /dev/somedisk` ?

Comment: I'd be much more worried about _why_ a fsck is required on each boot.

Comment: It's not needed on each boot, I'm trying to run it once ... but on the root filesystem *before* it gets mounted.

Comment: Are you trying to fsck a mounted partition [no-no]?  If not (as a one off), why do you need to reboot to do it ?  Is the solution you are looking for maybe to get a command prompt before the drive is mounted RW so you can check and repair it interactively ?  (If so, when booting, go into LILO/GRUB and append "init=/bin/bash" to your kernel line (and make sure the letters " ro " are there somewhere - which should be the default - to make sure its mounted read-only.

Comment: I need to `fsck` the root file system before it gets mounted by the OS ...

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to boot from usb/cd and run `fsck` from there without the hd mounted.

As for why you see different output, have a look at the accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14740/force-fsck-ext4-on-reboot-but-really-forceful). Basically, using the `-n` option of `fsck` on mounted file systems produces unreliable results.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really an option as this is a VPS.